# USING ALIAS in ORDER BY oR WHERE CLAUSE

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am running the following query:

```
     Select * From (SELECT pt.prod_desc AS"PROD_DESC",
  (
  CASE
 WHEN pt.prod_level='2'
THEN 'Product'
WHEN pt.prod_level='4'
THEN 'Sub-Product'
WHEN pt.prod_level='5'
THEN 'Service'
ELSE 'N/A'
 END)         AS"PROD_LEVEL",
 prod_id      AS "PROD_ID",
 isactive     AS "IsActive",
updt_usr_sid AS "UPDT_USR_SID",
 updt_ts      AS "UPDT_TS",
 (
  CASE
WHEN pt.prod_level='5'
THEN parent_prod_id
ELSE NULL
  END) AS ".SUB_PROD_ID",
  (
CASE
WHEN pt.prod_level='5'
THEN
  (SELECT prod_desc FROM dims_prod_type A WHERE A.prod_id= pt.parent_prod_id
  )
ELSE 'N/A'
   END ) AS ".SUB_PROD_DESC",
  (
  CASE
   WHEN pt.prod_level='4'
THEN parent_prod_id
WHEN pt.prod_level='5'
THEN
  (SELECT parent_prod_id
  FROM dims_prod_type A
  WHERE A.prod_id= pt.parent_prod_id
  )
ELSE NULL
END) AS ".PRNT_PROD_ID",
(
CASE
  WHEN pt.prod_level='4'
THEN
  (SELECT prod_desc FROM dims_prod_type A WHERE A.prod_id=pt.parent_prod_id
  )
WHEN pt.prod_level='5'
THEN
  (SELECT prod_desc
  FROM dims_prod_type A
  WHERE A.prod_id IN
    (SELECT B.parent_prod_id
    FROM dims_prod_type B
    WHERE b.prod_id=pt.parent_prod_id
    )
  )
ELSE 'N/A'
END)AS ".PRNT_PROD_DESC"
FROM dims_prod_type pt)A
  WHERE A.PRNT_PROD_ID is not null
 ORDER BY A.SUB_PROD_ID ASC
```

However it is throwing

```
        SQL Error: ORA-00904: "A"."SUB_PROD_ID": invalid identifier
      00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

error. Is there something wrong that i am doing here? I tried using group by/ even tried alias name As--? AS A but nothing seems to work. Please help me resolve the issue as i am not sure what step is that i am executing in an incorrect manner.

Comment: What is the use of adding(.) before alias name. Can u try by removing them

Answer (score 2):

Remove the dots in your aliases - `AS ".SUB_PROD_ID",` becomes `AS "SUB_PROD_ID",`; `AS ".PRNT_PROD_DESC"` becomes `AS "PRNT_PROD_DESC"`. Or, if you really *insist* on having dots in your alias name, change the last line to `ORDER BY A.".SUB_PROD_ID" ASC`.

Comment: And the double-quotes around the alias names aren't adding anything (once the dots are removed), and I think make it harder to read - as well as introducing the potential for a hard-to-spot error when the case is wrong somewhere.